# How to assign value in paste in R

Tags: r

How to assign a constant value to paste function

```
   a = 'age'
       (age in numeric)
```

I tried with  `df$key = paste0(df$name,df$a, sep="-")`

```
df
    name       age   
    A         23
    B         NA
    C         33
```

I am trying to get below df as:

```
df$key = paste0(df$name,df$a, sep="-")
```

which gives key as only name:

```
df
name       age    key
A         23      A-23
B         34      B-NA
C         33      C-33
```

Comment: df$a is actually matching df$age due to partial key matching. `a` is a separate object from `df` so remove the `df$` prefix.

Comment: What you are getting IS correct since you are trying to paste a character with a numeric variable (hence you're getting a character). I do not see what's wrong with that. Can you post what would you like to get as a result?

Answer (score 0):

we can call using  `df$key = paste0(df$name,df[,a], sep="-")`